# How can I use a bidirectional relationship filter with apoc.path.subgraphAll from only the start node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a dataset containing a large number of nodes linked by directional CONTROLS relationships. Say I have six nodes `A, B, C, D, E, F` and edges `B -> A, C -> B, D -> B, C -> E, D -> F`. I want to construct a Cypher / APOC query such that, when starting with `B`, I only get nodes `A, B, C, D`, i.e. expand bidirectionally *initially*, but not subsequently.

I can get the `A` and `B` with the following query:

`MATCH (n {id: "B"}) CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {relationshipFilter:'CONTROLS>'})`

However, if I wanted to get `C` and `D` as well, using `relationshipFilter: 'CONTROLS'`, I will also get `D` and `F` as well - which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter;  maxLevel: 1.  It will only filter nodes within 1 hop from B, thus will exclude D and F.

```
MATCH (n {id: "B"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "CONTROLS",
    maxLevel: 1
})
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships;
```

Comment: This only works in this particular simple case. With a deeper tree (let's say nodes `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H` and edges `B -> A, C -> B, D -> B, E -> C, F -> D, E -> G, F -> H`) I would not get `E` and `F` as desired while excluding `G` and `H` (nor can I know the depth in advance to use `maxLevel` appropriately).

Comment: With your new example, what is the difference on getting E and F but not G and H to your first simple example of getting C and D but not E and F? What is the logic? Looks like the logic is  "get nodes connected to B from maxPath minus 1".  Is it correct?